# Condition to be satisfied to print off-diagonal elements in a square matrix

Tags: python, python-2.7

What is the condition that must be satisfied to display the off-diagonal elements of a square matrix. For example,

```
L=123
  456
  789
```

The answer should be of the form:

```
   3
  5
 7
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Nope, I just want the condition.

Comment: With zero-based indexing, you would use `i + j == dim - 1`, where `i` and `j` are the indices and `dim` is the dimension of the matrix (3 in your example).

Comment: Hi Abel, you've tagged this question with python, yet you haven't shared any python code in your question. If somebody would know the answer (which I don't), it would be helpful to give more details about which libraries you're using. Also, if you've written code already, you should probably share this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> matrix=[[1,2,3],
            [4,5,6],
            [7,8,9]]
```

All the rows have equal lengths:

```
>>> l = len(matrix[0])
```

You want to iterate through the lists, start from the first row and take its third element and then the second element of the second row and so on:

```
>>> [matrix[l-1-i][i] for i in range(l-1,-1,-1)]
[3, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have taken hints from the answers above and have got it right, I guess.

```
n=input('Enter the no. of rows=')
a=[[0 for j in range(n)]for i in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
         a[i][j]=input()
print'\nInput Matrix is->'
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
         print a[i][j],' ',
    print

print'\nOff-diagonal elements are->'
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if i+j==n-1:
            print a[i][j],
        else: print ' ',
    print
```